# Django-Piston: ManyToManyField handling?

Tags: django, api, django-piston

Bit of a lazyweb question here: anybody know how django-piston handles writes (create/update) to ManyToMany fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't handle that. You need to explicitly override the "update" method for that.

Comment: Thanks Jesper. Any suggestions for how to handle it, particularly with create? I'm looking for a nice pattern around separating the creation of the main object from the creation of the related objects?